# How and what annotation should be used to modify POJOs to get required XML

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, stax

I need to generate and XML like in below code snippet where apart from *firstName*, *middleName* and *lastName* there will be many (around 50) elements for a player. For this XML, I need to have POJOs that will be used to generate XML using JAXB. Since, the player elements not only have values but also having attribute as well and according to my understanding I cannot declare properties inside player classes of primitive types rather each element will be a class.

```
<Players>
    <Player>
        <FirstName id="001">Mahendra</FirstName>
        <MiddleName id="002">Singh</MiddleName>
        <LastName id="003">Dhoni</LastName>
    </Player>
</Player>
```

But I don't want to create these 50 classes rather I think to have a single class that can be used for these all properties for a player but in that case the generated XML will look like:

```
<Players>
    <Player>
        <Property id="001">
            <Name>FirstName</Name>
            <Value>Mahendra</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property id="002">
            <Name>MiddleName</Name>
            <Value>Sing</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property id="003">
            <Name>LastName</Name>
            <Value>Dhoni</Value>
        </Property>
    </Player>
</Player>
```

What exactly I want here is that a way to give name to 'Property' tag with the value of 'Name' property that is inside the Property class and instead of having two child element viz. 'Name' and 'Value' only value of 'Value' appear in there. I mean how it this possible to get

```
<FirstName id="001">Mahendra</FirstName>
```

apart from

```
<Property id="001">
    <Name>FirstName</Name>
    <Value>Mahendra</Value>
</Property>
```

with having POJO as:

- Players.java

  `class Players
  {
      List<Player> player;
      //and getter setter
  }`
- Player.java

  `class Player
  {
      List<Property> property;
      // and getter setter
  }`
- Property.java

  `class Property
  {
      String name;
      String value;
      String id;
  }`

I haven't used any annotation here because I need to know what to put there to get what I want. :)

Comment: you can define your custom annotations for both elements and attributes which also can be use to serialize the Xmls.

Answer (score 0):

By this time you probably already solved this, put is a fun exercise and I had some free time.

Create a class in the package com.quick named StepByStep, remove all the IDE generated code (empty the file) before you coninue.

First add the package again

```
package com.quick;
```

First add the imports

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;

import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
```

Now, add some up classes

```
class Player {List<Property> property = new ArrayList<>();}

class Property {
    String id, name, value;
    public Property(String id, String name, String value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) // or write the get and set methods
class Players {
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(PlayerTypeAdapter.class) // dont worry about this line
    List<Player> player;
}
```

Now, add the XmlAdapter class (PlayerTypeAdapter), **this is the most important part, if you already know how @XmlJavaTypeAdapter works and you only want to know how to put arbitrary xml inside an element focus here**

```
class PlayerTypeAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Object, Player> {

    private DocumentBuilder documentBuilder;

    public PlayerTypeAdapter() {
        try {
            documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Player unmarshal(Object v) throws Exception {
        Player p = new Player();
        NodeList c = ((Element) v).getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < c.getLength(); i++) {
            Node n = c.item(i);
            if (!(n instanceof Element)) continue;
            Element e = (Element) n;
            p.property.add(new Property(e.getAttribute("id"), 
                e.getTagName(), e.getTextContent()));
        }
        return p;
    }

    @Override
    public Object marshal(Player v) throws Exception {
        Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();
        Element root = document.createElement("dummy");
        if (v.property != null) for (Property p : v.property) {
            Element propertyNode = document.createElement(p.name);
            propertyNode.setAttribute("id", p.id);
            propertyNode.setTextContent(p.value);
            root.appendChild(propertyNode);
        }
        return root;
    }
}
```

And finally add the StepByStep class with its main method (just to test our code)

```
public class StepByStep {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {

        // context, marshaller and unmarshaller
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Players.class, Player.class, Property.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

        // lets fill dummy players
        Players p = new Players();
        p.player = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            Player e = new Player();
            e.property.add(new Property("001", "FirstName", "Mahendra"));
            e.property.add(new Property("002", "MiddleName", "Sing"));
            e.property.add(new Property("003", "LastName", "Dhoni"));
            p.player.add(e);
        }

        // marshal p (original)
        ByteArrayOutputStream os1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        marshaller.marshal(p, os1);
        byte[] ba1 = os1.toByteArray();

        Players q = (Players) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new ByteArrayInputStream(ba1));

        // marshal q (copy)
        ByteArrayOutputStream os2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        marshaller.marshal(q, os2);
        byte[] ba2 = os2.toByteArray();

        // both q and p should be the same
        System.out.println(new String(ba1));
        System.out.println(new String(ba2));
    }

}
```